# ASP.NET MVC 4 Partial View does not reload at second time using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new with ASP.NET MVC 4. I have followed the tutorial to load partial view without refreshing whole page. The problem is that it only reloads at first time. In my `Index.cshtml` file:

```
<div id="detailsDiv">

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.setImage').click(function () {
        var url = "/Home/Test";
        var name = $(this).val();        
        $.post(url, { Name: name}, function (data) {            
            $("#detailsDiv").replaceWith(data);         
        });
    })
</script>
```

In my `HomeController.cs` file:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Test(string Name)
    {
        ConfigurationData cd = new ConfigurationData(Name, "xyz");
        return PartialView("Test", cd);
    }
```

My `Test.cshtml`:

```
@using Wordrific.Models.ParseFolder
@model ConfigurationData
<p id="abcde">@Model.ConfigurationVariables</p>
<p id="abcde">@Model.GameRules</p>
<p>test</p>
```

My problem is that it only reloads only once. I set the break point on the `Test.cshtml` file. I see the name is changed in the debug log but the browser does not update new data.

Comment: Use a free tool like Fiddler2 (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to check what is actually being sent and returned. It makes debugging ajax calls easy :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I mentioned the problem, in the debug log, the value of both ConfigurationVariables and GameRules are changed, but the browser displays old values, not the updated one

Comment: I am puzzled by this one as `post` requests should never be cached. What goes on inside the `ConfigurationData` constructor?

Comment: It's an object with 2 string variables(`ConfigurationsVariables` and `GameRules`)

Comment: Q: Are you running under IE8? (odd question I know, but this affects caching)

Comment: No, I test only on Chrome and Firefox

Comment: As a test: Try adding `[OutputCache(Duration=1)]` to your Test method. This should force it to ignore partial view caching (can't use `NoStore` or `Duration=0` with Partial Views).

Comment: I followed `[OutputCache(Duration=1)]`solution but it still does not work

Comment: I note your jQuery is not in a DOM ready handler... Where are the `class="setImage"` elements on the page? Can you show the entire HTML?

Comment: please add my email `nghia.nguyen170192@gmail.com` and I send you the html file

Comment: Message sent to your email. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can see, so far (until I get your full HTML), that might cause this is not using a DOM ready handler.

e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('.setImage').click(function () {
            var url = "/Home/Test";
            var name = $(this).val();        
            $.post(url, { Name: name}, function (data) {            
                $("#detailsDiv").replaceWith(data);         
            });
        });
    })
</script>
```

`$(function(){your code here});` is a shortcut for `$(document).ready(function(){your code here});`

Without this, correct operation would depend on the placement of the script within the page. If it preceded the elements with `class=setImage' there is a chance the code will fire before the elements are loaded.

Another way to avoid this sort of issue is using a deferred event handler.

e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', '.setImage', function () {
        var url = "/Home/Test";
        var name = $(this).val();        
        $.post(url, { Name: name}, function (data) {            
            $("#detailsDiv").replaceWith(data);         
        });
    });
</script>
```

This example listens for `click` events that bubble-up to the `document` level (which will always be present), *then* applies a jQuery filter to match elements, *then* applies the function to any matching elements *that caused the event*.

As a general rule though, use a DOM ready handler.

Comment: The problem is that `ConfigurationVariables` and `GameRules` are passed to partial view. I check in the debug log and there are updated values, not the old values, but the browser doesnt display updated values

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#detailsDiv").replaceWith(data);
```

replaceWith is replacing the whole detailsDiv that is why the second attempt is failing because it cannot find the detailsDiv anymore. Use the following code instead.

```
$("#detailsDiv").html(data);
```